# Trigger a DAG Run from a python

Tags: python, airflow, etl

I wrote a python program to create a DAG file. After creating this DAG file, I want to trigger this DAG run. I tried to use the following code -

```
from airflow.api.client.local_client import Client

c = Client(None, None)
c.trigger_dag(dag_id='local_job_md', run_id='local_job_md', conf={})
```

But this code is getting error as it is not able to find DAG table in sqlite. After little research, I realized this might be an issue for some gaps in installation. I am new to API but I realized that there is a way to use stable Rest API to trigger the DAG from my program. I need help in this from you people. I want to trigger the DAG from my code badly.

Please help me out from such a situation. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,

Jay

Answer (score 0):

Even though you only want to use the API, you still need to initialize the Airflow DB. Unable to find the `dag` table in sqlite means you don't have your `airflow.db` initialized.

To do this, go to your `$AIRFLOW_HOME` directory and run:

```
airflow initdb
```

If this command doesn't work for you, you may not have set up Airflow correctly, so I'd suggest starting with the install steps from the beginning.